# How to add SAMAccountName to output?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Stuck on how to add SAMAccounts (AD usernames) to the results, can anyone help, currently getting no results in the list SamAccountName?

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | where 
{$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq 
$false} | 
Select Identity,User,SamAccountName,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression= 
{[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation 
C:\temp\mailboxpermissions1.csv
```

No results showing for SAMAccountName

Comment: Don't think samaccountname is retrieved by Get-Mailbox. Might want to pipe it into Get-ADUser :)

Comment: The permission object returned by `Get-MailboxPermission` contains an `Identity` property (not `SamAccountName`)

Answer (score 2):

SamAccountName is not available through `Get-Mailbox` or `Get-MailboxPermission` but you can get it with `Get-User` with calculated property, see example:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | 
where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | 
Select Identity,User,@{N="SamAccountName";E={(Get-User $_.Identity).SamAccountName}},@{Name='Access Rights';Expression= {[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\mailboxpermissions1.csv
```

Comment: Hi, tried your example and the results for Sam Account came out blank. The Identity of the shared account shows, username of user with access shows, rights show just not the username of the shared accounts that is needed!

Comment: what exchange version you're using?

Comment: Exchange 2010  SP3

Answer (score 0):

You can get SamAccountName using Get-Mailbox cmdlet.

```
((Get-Mailbox -Filter '*')[0] | Get-Member).Name

# Results
<#
PS C:\Scripts> ((Get-Mailbox -Filter '*')[0] | Get-Member).Name
...
RoomMailboxAccountEnabled
RulesQuota
SamAccountName
SCLDeleteEnabled
...
#>

Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' | ForEach {$PSItem.SamAccountName}

# Results
<#
 Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' | ForEach {$PSItem.SamAccountName}
Administrator
...
#>
```

It just does not get passed down the pipeline as being stated here...

***Example:***

```
(Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' -ResultSize Unlimited).SamAccountName | 
ForEach{Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $PSItem} | 
Where-Object {
    $PSItem -ne 'NT AUTHORITY\SELF' -and 
    $PSItem.IsInherited -eq $false
} | Select-Object -Property '*'

# Results
<#
AccessRights    : {FullAccess, ReadPermission}
Deny            : False
InheritanceType : All
User            : NT AUTHORITY\SELF
Identity        : contoso.com/Users/Administrator
IsInherited     : False
IsValid         : True
ObjectState     : Unchanged

...
#>
```

***So, try it this way...***

```
(Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' -ResultSize Unlimited).SamAccountName | 
ForEach{Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $PSItem} | 
Where-Object {
    $PSItem -ne 'NT AUTHORITY\SELF' -and 
    $PSItem.IsInherited -eq $false
} | Select-Object -Property Identity,User,
@{Name = 'SamAccountName';Expression = {(Get-ADUser -Identity $($PSitem.Identity -split '/')[-1]).SamAccountName}},
@{Name = 'Access Rights';Expression = {[string]::join(', ', $PSItem.AccessRights)}}

# Results
<#
Identity                              User                SamAccountName   Access Rights                       
--------                              ----                --------------   -------------                       
contoso.com/Users/Administrator     NT AUTHORITY\SELF   Administrator    FullAccess, ReadPermission          
... 
#>
```

***Update for the OP***

As for you comment...

> Hi, this errors out : Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'Filter'
>   to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Invalid filter syntax. For
>   a description of the filter parameter syntax see the command help. "*"
>   at position 1."

… as noted from my comment before this update.

The sample is all raw normal PowerShell, and should work local or remote (as long as you have PSRemoting setup properly and you are local admin on the remote box and you are running this as that admin)

If you run this …

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ex01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' -ResultSize Unlimited}
```

or this...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ex01 -ScriptBlock {(Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' -ResultSize Unlimited).SamAccountName}
```

Or this...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ex01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Mailbox -Filter '*' -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName}
```

... by itself in your environment over a PSRemoting session, what happens?

If you are doing your PSRemoting session, like this...

```
$ExpSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName 'Microsoft.Exchange' -ConnectionUri ("http://$Ex01Fqdn/PowerShell") -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Creds

Import-PSSession $ExpSession
```

Then you don't need the Invoke-Command at all, since the cmdlets are already proxied to your workstation. Just run the code as is.

***Example - Implicit PSRemoting session, leveraging -Prefix***

This -prefix is not absolutely required, it's just a habit I've standardize on using for all my implicit remote sessions. The -prefix is recommend if you are using say both Exchange Online cmdlets and the Exchange on-prem cmdlets on the same box to avoid confusion and errors.):

```
($ExpSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName 'Microsoft.Exchange' -ConnectionUri ("http://$Ex01Fqdn/PowerShell") -Authentication Default)

<#
 Id Name            ComputerName    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  8 Session8        ex01.contoso... Opened        Microsoft.Exchange       Available
#>


Import-PSSession $ExpSession -Prefix 'EXP'

<#
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'tmp_zucxz5zd.0ee' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands wi
th unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                             
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                             
Script     1.0        tmp_zucxz5zd.0ee                    {Add-EXPADPermission, Add-EXPAvai...
#>

(Get-ExpMailbox -Filter '*' -ResultSize Unlimited).SamAccountName | 
ForEach{Get-ExpMailboxPermission -Identity $PSItem} | 
Where-Object {
    $PSItem -ne 'NT AUTHORITY\SELF' -and 
    $PSItem.IsInherited -eq $false
} | Select-Object -Property Identity,User,
@{Name = 'SamAccountName';Expression = {(Get-ADUser -Identity $($PSitem.Identity -split '/')[-1]).SamAccountName}},
@{Name = 'Access Rights';Expression = {[string]::join(', ', $PSItem.AccessRights)}}

# The results would be the same as my original response.
```

Comment: Hi, this errors out : Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Invalid filter syntax. For
a description of the filter parameter syntax see the command help.
"*" at position 1."

Comment: I ran my code directly on an Exchange server, not in a PSRemoting session and as shown the code works as per the results. At no point did you state in the post that you were doing this in a remote session, nor did you show this in your posted code sample, even here. The sample is all raw normal PowerShell, and should work local or remote (as long as you have PSRemoting setup properly and you are running this as an admin of that server target). See my update for you showing a PSRemote session.

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id. What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??